# Generate access token using JWT

Tags: jwt, okta

I've been given access to an okta token endpoint.  I would like to use this service to request a token.  I was given a url, client id, client secret, scope and grant type.  I can use postman to make a POST call to the url (/v1/token) and pass the above info (client id, client secret, scope and grant type) and I get an access token back.

I can easily make this call in java with RestTemplate or equivalent, but I would like to use an API that would manage the token for me.

I've found JJWT.  All the examples I see out there show me how to create a JWT using JJWT.  What I would like to do is to get my access token, but I'm not sure how to do that. I mean i get that JJWT is an API to create JWT, but then how can I use the JWT to get my access token?

Any help/clarification/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We using JWT with the node.js, to create new Token `jwt.sign(data, key)` takes at least to an argument, the fist must be some credential like userId, email..., the second will be key to verify later. to verify the token is it valid we use `jwt.verify()`, the first argument is token (where the `jwt.sing()` give you) and the second is the key (where you provide when creating);

example:

Creating JWT token:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
cosnt token = jwt.sign({ email: 'test@test.com', userId: '993333' }, 'secretkey');
```

verifying Token:

```
try {
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey');
} 
catch(err) { 
   throw new Error(err) 
}

 // once verified 
 conosole.log(decodedToken)
```

I found [this post](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/31/jwts-with-java) how to create and verify token using java, thanks!